# select statement max date

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table which i use for a list and i want now from this table from a spesific order_key the highest date.

```
  SELECT to_char(max(to_date(list_description,'DD.MM.YYYY'))) list_Description, id
  from VW_TA04_BAG_5B
  where bac_order = '00010001'
  group by id
```

This is my result

```
 20-MAR-17  1
    08-MAR-17   2
    06-JUN-17   3
    02-MAY-18   4
    03-MAY-18   5
```

But i want only this as my output

```
03-MAY-18   5
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to store Dates as string.

Comment: What is the rule to filter only that line?

Comment: yes only that one

Comment: Why that one and not `06-JUN-17   3`?

Comment: because of the year, 03-may-18 is one year later

Comment: [MySQL doesn't provide any `to_date()` or `to_char()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/func-op-summary-ref.html). They are [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129) [functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132). Please tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle you can try something like this.

```
SELECT
      LIST_DESCRIPTION,
      ID
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(T.LIST_DESCRIPTION,'DD.MM.YYYY')) LIST_DESCRIPTION,
          T.ID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TO_DATE(T.LIST_DESCRIPTION,
          'DD.MM.YYYY') DESC) RNK
        FROM
          VW_TA04_BAG_5B T
        WHERE
          BAC_ORDER = '00010001'
      )
    WHERE
      RNK=1;
```

Comment: i got the same result

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear. Apparently you want to get only the line

```
03-MAY-18   5
```

*"because of the year, 03-may-18 is one year later"*. I guess this means you need the row that has the greatest date in the `list_Description` column.

You don't need `GROUP BY` for that. A simple `ORDER BY list_Description DESC` combined with a limit of one row is enough (and runs much faster):

```
SELECT to_char(list_Description), id
FROM (
    SELECT to_date(list_description,'DD.MM.YYYY') list_Description, id
    FROM VW_TA04_BAG_5B
    WHERE bac_order = '00010001'
    ORDER BY list_Description DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted(where clause is missig). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Order the records and take only the first

```
  SELECT to_char(max(to_date(list_description,'DD.MM.YYYY'))) list_Description, id
  from VW_TA04_BAG_5B
  where bac_order = '00010001'
  group by id
  order by id desc
  limit 1
```

Comment: The query is correct for MySQL. Unfortunately the OP tagged the question as [tag:mysql] when in fact they are using [tag:oracle].

Comment: sorry for that, I just started working as an apprentice and tought it wold be the same for both.

Answer (score 1):

One more variation, using [`keep last`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions095.htm):

```
select max(to_date(list_description,'DD.MM.YYYY')) as list_description,
  max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by to_date(list_description,'DD.MM.YYYY')) as id
from VW_TA04_BAG_5B
where bac_order = '00010001';

LIST_DESC         ID
--------- ----------
03-MAY-18          5
```

This (and the other answers) assume you're storing dates as strings, which is bad design. If `list_description` is actually a date - which seems unlikely from the name - then you are doing implicit conversions which might break in a different environment, and you would instead just need to do:

```
select max(list_description) as list_description,
  max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by list_description) as id
from VW_TA04_BAG_5B
where bac_order = '00010001';
```

However you do it, you need to at least consider what you want to happen if two rows for a BACS ID have exactly the same date (or string!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12C, just order your result and FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_DATE(list_description,'DD.MM.YYYY'))) list_Description, id
  FROM VW_TA04_BAG_5B
  WHERE bac_order = '00010001'
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY list_Description DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```